# Check before Inserting values trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, constraints

I have a table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Vaccination]
(
    [MedicalID] [int] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [VaccineName] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [VaccineDate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [DoseNo] [int] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [FacilityName] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
)
```

So I have a constraint that allows only 2 values into the table: dose 1 and dose 2

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Vaccination] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT No_of_Doses CHECK ([DoseNo] = 1 OR [DoseNo] = 2)
```

I want to create a trigger where the value for 2nd dose to be inserted only if 1st does exist else display an error message. Also the 1st dose to be inserted without any problems.

Here is my attempt to it:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Dose1Check
ON [dbo].[Vaccination]
BEFORE INSERT
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Vaccination]
        SELECT 22, 'Moderna', '2022-04-22', 1, 'CVS'
        WHERE IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
                         FROM [dbo].[Vaccination]
                         WHERE [MedicalID] = 22 AND [DoseNo] = 1)
            SELECT * 
            FROM [dbo].[Vaccination];
END
```

The following part of the code of the above trigger, when executed independently, is not allowing me to insert the 1st dose as well.

```
 INSERT INTO [dbo].[Vaccination]
     SELECT 22, 'Moderna', '2022-04-22', 1, 'CVS'
     WHERE 
         IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
                    FROM [dbo].[Vaccination]
                    WHERE [MedicalID] = 22 AND [DoseNo] = 1)
             SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Vaccination];
```

Here are some values for the table

```
MedicalID,  VaccineName,    VaccineDate,    DoseNo, FacilityName
14, Moderna,    2022-04-22, 1,  Daisy Family Health
14, Moderna,    2022-04-26, 2,  Daisy Family health
15, Moderna,    2022-04-28, 1,  Daisy Family Health
15, Moderna,    2022-04-22, 2,  Daisy Family Health
16, Pfizer, BioNTech,   2022-04-28  1   Daisy Family Health
```

Comment: Your code is not valid tsql, `where if exists` would be a syntax error. Why are you hard-coding values in the trigger? I don't think you have you read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver15) regarding triggers?

Comment: And SQL Server doesn't have any `BEFORE INSERT` triggers, either ...

Comment: There are multiple issues with your trigger code. Triggers should not return resultsets. Your trigger is inserted a hard-coded row - which makes no sense at all. Use of specific ID values is generally never a good idea - why use 22 for Medical ID? Lastly, you need to think differently. Your trigger should **prevent** a second dose row from being inserted - it should not simply add a row. And stop the laziness - always supply a column list in an insert statement and always use statement terminators. Learn good habits.

Comment: Personally I think you should consider why you need  to specify `DoseNo` in the first place. Dose 2 should just be the row after the first one, and use `ROW_NUMBER` to number them when you query them

Comment: Why are you using a trigger for data integrity?

Answer (score 1):

First your sample data imply the table has a composite primary key `(MedicalID,  DoseNo)`. Thus

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Vaccination](
    [MedicalID] [int] NOT NULL ,
    [VaccineName] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [VaccineDate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [DoseNo] [int] NOT NULL CHECK (DoseNo IN (1,2)),
    [FacilityName] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    Primary Key ([MedicalID],[DoseNo])
)
```

You can check if inserted data contain out of order doseNo with a trigger

```
create trigger Dose1Check
  on [dbo].[Vaccination]
  after insert as
begin
  if exists (
    select 1
    from ( -- check single dose insertions only
          select [MedicalID], max(DoseNo) DoseNo
          from inserted
          group by [MedicalID]
          having count(*) = 1
    ) i
    left join [dbo].[Vaccination] v on i.[MedicalID] = v.[MedicalID] and v.DoseNo = 1
    where v.[MedicalID] is null and i.DoseNo = 2 )
  begin
      RAISERROR ('Bad DoseNo' , 16, 1)
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
  end
end
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0fc8e5dba411b384aa03c0447bb58249)

Comment: Throw - not raiserror

Comment: Thank you so much @Serg. this helped me a lot with my project !!!

Comment: Instead of `RAISERROR` and `ROLLBACK` (which will cause a spurious `Transaction ended in the trigger` error) use `THROW 50001, 'Bad Dose Number', 1;`